# Where can I find PSM resources outside of the Scrum Guide?

Tags: scrum, scrum-master, certification

I took the PSM about a month ago and almost made it, but sadly I didn't pass. I had a pretty good understanding of the material, but the main thing that tripped me up was around running scrum with multiple teams. That's where my gap in knowledge is, as I've used the scrum guide,my work experience (We started using scrum recently) and a senior PM who has experience in Scrum as my basis for studying and learning.

I wanted to ask if anyone had some resources I could use to further my knowledge and better prepare me for my 2nd go at the PSM. Specifically things that [the Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) doesn't cover. Thanks so much!

Comment: Scrum is a single-team framework. Multiple teams requires a scaled agile framework like Nexus, LeSS, SAFe, Scrum of Scrums, or whatever. Are you *sure* your material is suggesting otherwise?

Comment: Search-type questions about off-site resources are out of scope. This question would be on-topic if revised to focus on how to address multi-team issues or to solve a particular problem, but requesting a reading list makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Scrum.org provides a [Learning Path for Scrum Masters](https://www.scrum.org/pathway/scrum-master). It links to videos, blogs, books and other helpful things to help you prepare.

The PSM assessment is pretty strict on the Scrum Guide's guidance on working with multiple teams:

> The Product Owner is the sole person responsible for managing the Product Backlog.

_

> Multiple Scrum Teams often work together on the same product. One Product Backlog is used to describe the upcoming work on the product. A Product Backlog attribute that groups items may then be employed.

_

> If "Done" for an increment is not a convention of the development organization, the Development Team of the Scrum Team must define a definition of "Done" appropriate for the product. If there are multiple Scrum Teams working on the system or product release, the Development Teams on all the Scrum Teams must mutually define the definition of "Done".

_

> A Sprint Review is held at the end of the Sprint to inspect the Increment and adapt the Product Backlog if needed.

See: https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html

When applying Scrum to scale Scrum, these basic rules officially still apply. Nexus and LeSS stay mostly within this set of constraints. Nexus+ and LeSS Huge break some of these constraints. SAFe by default overrules all of these constraints.

Comment: It is worth noting that from this link it looks like the big focus from Scrum.org (the people who offer the PSM) is on Nexus as a scaling framework. That is confusing to say the least as there is nothing that makes Nexus more officially scrum than any other scaling framework, but I guess if you want their cert, you have to know the stuff they think is important.

Comment: The PSM materials doesn't enforce Nexus. But it does not violate the rules of scrum according to the Scrum Guide. So there is a single product owner per product (as per the scrum guide) and there is a single review per product (as per the Scrum guide). Nexus is very true to the Scrum guide in that sense. Other Scaling frameworks take more liberty on these rules.

Answer (score 1):

As a Professional Scrum Master, I also did my research when I was studying for the exam.

My first advice is to read the and understand the [scrum guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) at 100%.

The best and free online exam that I found, where you can find real exam questions, and I personally recommend, is this one: [Mlapshin scrum quizzes](https://mlapshin.com/index.php/scrum-quizzes/)

I did it until I had all answers right many times.

Good luck!